# Error with different date format between C# and T-SQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, datetime

I have problem with datetime format for C# and T-SQL.

- C# application is using DD.MM.YYYY HH.mm.SS format
- T-SQL is using MM\DD\YYYY HH.mm.SS format

Obviously T-SQL returns `Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.` error.

Is there a way how to check and transform datetime format on SQL side? I would like T-SQL to be able to use DD.MM.YYY format.

Thanks.

Comment: T-SQL doesn't use any string formatting - a `DateTime` is a  `DateTime` is a  `DateTime` and doesn't have any formatting associated with it. You should use either parametrized queries, or if you really must have a date in string format, use the **ISO-8601** standard format (`YYYYMMDD` or `YYYYMMDDTHH:MM:SS`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to avoid this kind of issue.

When you build your SQL as a string to pass to SQL Server, you not only encounter this kind of issue, but may also be exposing yourself to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

With parameterized queries, you would be passing in a `DateTime` value and the DB library would do the right thing.

Formats don't come into play as they are only used for *display*.

Comment: I am using parameters: sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime_from", DatetimeFrom);

Comment: @feronovak - What type is `DatetimeFrom`? Can you post your full code?